# How can I disable the div using jquery before button submit

Tags: jquery

I have two divs called "Yes" and "No"

```
<div id="object">
    <div class="object-content">
        I'd say
        <div class="confirm" id="btnYes" runat ="server" >Yes</div>
    </div>
    <div class="object-content" style="float: right">
        I'd say
        <div class="confirm" style="color: red"  id="btnNo" runat="server">No</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And one Comment button called "Post"

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPostUrComment" OnClick="btnPostUrComment_Click" runat="server" Text="Post Your Comment" Height="33px" class="ppig" />
```

When I directly click on the "Post" I alert "Please select Yes or NO by clicking on them"
And click on the "yes" or "no" div I alert "You said "Yes" or "no" "

Now the problem is , after all this If I click "yes" div then the "no" div will be disable not hide before click on "Post" button and vice versa .

I am trying some script. Please guide me.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var IsPostComment = false;
    var clickedElement = "";

    $('.confirm').click(function () {
        IsPostComment = true;
        clickedElement = $(this).text();
    });

    $('#<%=btnPostUrComment.ClientID %>').click(function () {
        if (IsPostComment) {
            alert("You Said " + clickedElement);

        } else {
            alert("Please select Yes or NO by clicking on them")
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: not getting your problem statement. please elaborate it more.

Comment: when i click on the yes div the no div will be disable and vice versa .

Answer (score 0):

this id the correct way

```
$('.confirm').click(function () {
        IsPostComment = true;
        clickedElement = $(this).text();
        var x=$(this).attr("id");
        if(var x=="btnYes")
        {
               $('#btnNo').disable();
        }
      else
      {
              $('#btnYes').disable();
       }
    });
```

Comment: 'disabled' is not css but attribute in html.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var IsPostComment = false;
    var clickedElement = "";

    $('.confirm').click(function () {
        // disable other button
        var disableBtnId = ($(this).attr('id')=='btnYes')?'btnNo':'btnYes';
        $('#'+disableBtnId).prop('disabled',true);

        IsPostComment = true;
        clickedElement = $(this).text();
    });

    $('#<%=btnPostUrComment.ClientID %>').click(function () {
        // enable both buttons
        $('.confirm').removeProp('disabled');

        if (IsPostComment) {
            alert("You Said " + clickedElement);

        } else {
            alert("Please select Yes or NO by clicking on them")
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var IsPostComment = false;
    var clickedElement = "";

     $('.confirm').click(function () {
            IsPostComment = true;
            clickedElement = $(this).text();
            var mydiv=$(this).attr("id");
            if(mydiv=="btnYes")
            {
                   $('#btnNo').hide();
                   $('#btnYes').show();
            }
          else
          {
                  $('#btnYes').hide();
                  $('#btnNo').show();
           }
        });

    $('#<%=btnPostUrComment.ClientID %>').click(function () {
        if (IsPostComment) {
            alert("You Said " + clickedElement);

        } else {
            alert("Please select Yes or NO by clicking on them")
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```